# Word for working at a certain post but not made official

Tags: promotion, position

I am working as a Project Manager from the last few months but my official designation is still of a software engineer. The official role change will happen next year but I want to use "Project Manager" as my designation because I want recruiters see me in that position. Is there any word which can specify this?

[I saw some profiles on LinkedIn writing "Manager (Designate)" - is "designate" the word I am looking for?]

Comment: What's going to happen if you just change your designation? You're talking about LinkedIn, right? Is anyone going to care what you put there?

Comment: Cross-posted to ELU https://english.stackexchange.com/q/461805/305308

Comment: Sorry, @Phoenix, I know that you are new, but we do not accept cross-posting on any S.E sites, and doing so is likely to get your questions downvoted and/or deleted. Sometimes, it's a tough decision, but you (and I) just have to make a choice and go with it.

Comment: Hi Phoenix, and welcome to the Workplace.  Unfortunately, cross-posting the same question into different sites is discouraged here.  Please see [this Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) for more information.  Please continue with this question where you first asked it, which is the appropriate site for this question.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been cross-posted from another site (https://english.stackexchange.com/q/461805/305308)

Comment: @Snow Actually someone from the other site advised me to ask the question here. And frankly I have got more responses here!

Answer (score 1):

"Interim" is another word I see quite a lot.

So

> Interim Project Manager

Would be widely understood.

Answer (score 1):

The word[s] you are looking for is "interim", "pro tem", or "[pro tempore](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_tempore)".  That being said,  just calling yourself a project manager is probably not a big deal. You can always clarify when asked about details.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, if you defacto project manager with "designation" within the company is coming later, i don`t get the delay  BTW, and you get PM salary, responsibilities etc, 
then you are actual PM, not interim or temporary

Answer (score 0):

"acting project manager"

One of the definitions of "acting" in the Oxford English Dictionary is

> Of a person: doing a job nominally shared with another or others who
>   may not have an active role; (also) temporarily doing the job or
>   duties of another. Chiefly preceding a title of office or occupation.

with example quotations such as "2008   Lloyd's List (Nexis) 8 May 3   Stanley Sher is to be interim acting president until Mr Koch's return." and "1938   A. W. Griswold Far Eastern Policy of U.S. ii. 63   He served as Assistant Secretary of State under Olney, during part of which period..he filled the gap between Olney and Sherman as Acting Secretary."